# JavaScript filter object resemble key name and push to arr

Tags: javascript, object

This is my question:

```
const arr = [];
const Picture = {
  PictureDescription1: "this is description 1",
  PictureDescription2: "this is description 2",
  PictureDescription3: "this is description 3",
  PictureUrl1:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/8b20ab7e-90e0-49a8-9137-d140fa5d369a.jpg",
  PictureUrl2:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/7da4b849-11a7-46c8-96fb-412f187ad8bf.jpg",
  PictureUrl3:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/f04581ce-6b16-46cd-9af3-5661276b9b68.jpg", 
}
```

and I want to make url and descirption to a group and push to a arr. This was my way, but I think it too lengthy:

```
if(Picture.PictureUrl1) {
 arr.push({
  url: Picture.PictureUrl1,
  description: Picture.PictUrlDescription1
 })
}

if(Picture.PictureUrl2) {
 arr.push({
  url: Picture.PictureUrl2,
  description: Picture.PictUrlDescription2
 })
}

if(Picture.PictureUrl3) {
 arr.push({
  url: Picture.PictureUrl3,
  description: Picture.PictUrlDescription3
 })
}
```

Is there any ohter way to do this?

Comment: Are you in control of the Picture data structure? It seems a bit unuseful. I'd consider changing that if you're in control of it.

Answer (score 0):

A loop over `[1, 2, 3]` with bracket notation to look up the appropriate property would work.

```js
const Picture = {
  PictureDescription1: "this is description 1",
  PictureDescription2: "this is description 2",
  PictureDescription3: "this is description 3",
  PictureUrl1:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/8b20ab7e-90e0-49a8-9137-d140fa5d369a.jpg",
  PictureUrl2:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/7da4b849-11a7-46c8-96fb-412f187ad8bf.jpg",
  PictureUrl3:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/f04581ce-6b16-46cd-9af3-5661276b9b68.jpg", 
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
  .filter(num => Picture['PictureUrl' + num])
  .map(num => ({
    url: Picture['PictureUrl' + num],
    description: Picture['PictureDescription' + num]
  }));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version that will work with any number of properties in `obj`:

```js
const obj = {
  PictureDescription1: "this is description 1",
  PictureDescription2: "this is description 2",
  PictureDescription3: "this is description 3",
  PictureUrl1:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/8b20ab7e-90e0-49a8-9137-d140fa5d369a.jpg",
  PictureUrl2:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/7da4b849-11a7-46c8-96fb-412f187ad8bf.jpg",
  PictureUrl3:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/f04581ce-6b16-46cd-9af3-5661276b9b68.jpg", 
}

const arr=Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>k.slice(0,10)=="PictureUrl")
   .map(k=>({url:obj[k], description: obj[k.replace("Url","Description")]}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Picture = {
  PictureDescription1: "this is description 1",
  PictureDescription2: "this is description 2",
  PictureDescription3: "this is description 3",
  PictureUrl1:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/8b20ab7e-90e0-49a8-9137-d140fa5d369a.jpg",
  PictureUrl2:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/7da4b849-11a7-46c8-96fb-412f187ad8bf.jpg",
  PictureUrl3:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/f04581ce-6b16-46cd-9af3-5661276b9b68.jpg", 
}

const urls = Object.keys(Picture).filter(e => e.includes('Url'));

const arr = urls.map((e) => {
    const descriptionKey = 'PictureDescription' + e[e.length - 1];
    const description = Picture[descriptionKey] ?? '';
    return {
        url: Picture[e],
        description: Picture[descriptionKey]
    }
})

console.log(arr);
```

Identify url keys with a logic and then iterate over it to check for description related to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce` implementation.

Taking into consideration that the keys are always `PictureDescription` and `PictureUrl` plus an index

```js
const Picture = {
    PictureDescription1: "this is description 1",
    PictureDescription2: "this is description 2",
    PictureDescription3: "this is description 3",
    PictureUrl1:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/8b20ab7e-90e0-49a8-9137-d140fa5d369a.jpg",
    PictureUrl2:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/7da4b849-11a7-46c8-96fb-412f187ad8bf.jpg",
    PictureUrl3:"https://www.taiwan.net.tw/att/event/f04581ce-6b16-46cd-9af3-5661276b9b68.jpg", 
}
const arr = Object.entries(Picture).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const [key, value] = curr;
    if(key.includes('PictureDescription')) {
        const index = +key[key.length - 1];
        acc.push({
            url: Picture[`PictureUrl${index}`],
            description: Picture[`PictureDescription${index}`]
        })
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 syntax you can do something like this.

```js
[1,2,3].map(item=>({url:Picture[`PictureUrl${item}`],description:Picture[`PictureDescription${item}`]}))
```